# Dependency injection and event handling

Tags: c++, events, dependency-injection

```
class ITransportProvider
{
public:
    virtual ~ITransportProvider() { }

protected:
    virtual void SendData() = 0;
    // Concrete TransportProvider will call OnReceiveDataEvent

    // virtual void RegisterHandlers(std::function<void()> onReceiveDataEvent);
}

class Device
{
public:
    Device(shared_ptr<ITransportProvider> transport)
        : m_Transport(transport)
    {
        // transport->RegisterHandlers(boost::bind(&Device::OnReceiveData, this));
    }

    void SendData()
    {
        m_Transport->SendData();
    }

    // Which design pattern to use to get concrete TransportProvider's OnReceiveData event?
    //void OnReceiveData()
    //{
    //}

private:
    shared_ptr<ITransportProvider> m_Transport;
};
```

I've always added a "RegisterHandlers" in my ITransportProvider and make Device call it in its c'tor.
I'd like to know if its correctness in the eyes of DI/IoC gurus and would love to hear all suggestions.

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm asking if there's a better way of decoupling TransportProvider from Device besides the above way which is via DI and the Observer pattern.

Comment: The comment for `ITransportProvider::OnReceiveData()` says that it will be called by a concrete TransportProvider, but since it is pure virtual, it will also need to be implemented by the concrete TransportProvider, so it seems odd that it is part of the abstract interface.

Comment: @VaughnCato OnReceiveData shouldn't be in the interface -- I added it in to illustrate a callback which I thought would make it clearer (but it clearly doesn't, so I'll remove it).

Comment: You'll want to be careful, since the Device destructor needs to unregister the callback.  You might want to use a slot mechanism instead, which could use RAII.

Comment: @VaughnCato In my actual code, OnReceiveData has an argument of `shared_ptr<Device>` and m_Transport->Close() is called in the Device d'tor. Some of the details I've left out simply because I wanted to get feedback on the design pattern itself rather than the actual implementations.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on the pattern you are trying to describe.  How specific is it?  What are the alternatives?

Comment: @VaughnCato It's basic DI and I'm just asking if the RegisterHandlers way I've always done is bad/good/ok design, and if there are other better ways of implementing such callbacks from a DI/IoC perspective.

Comment: Yes, but what do you consider important about this?  That you are providing some mechanism for methods to be called of Device as opposed to putting the logic directly in a concrete TransportProvider?

Comment: @VaughnCato I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why I'm choosing to implement the provider pattern?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16854/discussion-between-zach-saw-and-vaughn-cato

Answer (score 0):

You have a reasonable design.  Decoupling can be handled at many different levels in different ways with various trade-offs.  Your design is good for the case where you know the sending and receiving are related, but there is no particular compile-time relationship between Device instances and Transport implementations.  If there was a compile-time relationship, you might use policy-based design:

```
class TransportProviderA
{
public:
    void SendData();
    virtual void OnReceiveData() = 0;
}

template <typename TransportPolicy>
class Device : public TransportPolicy
{
public:
    Device(const TransportPolicy &transport_policy)
        : TransportPolicy(transport_policy)
    {
    }

    // SendData provided by TransportPolicy

    virtual void OnReceiveData(); // overrides TransportPolicy's template method.
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
Device<TransportPolicyA> my_device(TransportPolicyA());
```